# It's time we managed [time-management]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Tags [time-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-management) and [time-tracking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-tracking) both exist. With very few questions (44 total) and haven't been used in a year (or two).

Perhaps these should be synonyms. I'd say keep time-management, but time-tracking already has a synonym.

Comment: [time-management] is definitely limited to human productivity.  [time-tracking] has mixed usage, including tracking time of computer activity.  It might be better to add some wiki excerpts.  Re-tag the [time-tracking] questions that relate to human productivity as [time-management], and leave the ones related to computer activity.

Comment: And now that I look at the questions, I see people have used [time-management] to also refer to computer activity (how surprising is that?).  So those questions would get re-tagged with [time-tracking].  Another possibility: also rename the tags for clarity, like [human-time-management], and [computer-process-time-tracking], or something.

Comment: Is there a difference **on superuser**? My thoughts are if it's on topic here, it needs to be about the same thing - not the same as "timer" or "date and time" or [compiling](http://xkcd.com/303/)...

Comment: There's a collection of stuff about human productivity software, and another collection of stuff about computer process times.  I would think those should be separate topics.

Comment: That may be a good point, perhaps a retag of the human collection just to [productivity] and then everything else goes to whichever one stays.

Comment: Let me browse the questions.  There's an existing [productivity] that's a motley collection, but it includes stuff other than time management.  Then there's [to-do], which is similar to time management.  [tasks], which is another mix of meat and silicon.  I assume [time-tracking] probably includes some stuff like accounting software, which a lot of people would distinguish from time management.  [scheduling] probably overlaps.  Sometimes the best way is to start peeling off stuff that obviously goes somewhere else.as a 1st step.

Comment: This will take a little longer than I thought.  So far, I've found over 2 doz inter-related tags.

Comment: The bigger picture on human productivity questions needs work.  [time-management] has now been cleaned up to refer only to people questions.   We could at least make some progress by retagging the people-based [time-tracking] questions to [time-management] and limiting the [time-tracking] tag to computer-based questions.  Any tag cleanup will need to differentiate those questions, anyway.

Comment: Good work @fixer1234